# getClass() returning java.lang.Class [Reflection]

Tags: java, reflection

So upon getting the parameter(s) for a method via Reflection:

```
Class<?>[] params = m.getParameterTypes();
```

And assuming I'm looping through methods and looking for a method with only one parameter:

```
if(params.length > 1) {
     continue;
}
```

Then getting that parameter if the length of the params array is 1:

```
Class<?> par = params[0];
```

When I try printing out the parameter's class with the getClass() method, it returns java.lang.Class.

However, when I get the superclass with the getSuperclass() method, it returns the superclass.

So for example:

```
System.out.println(par.getClass());
System.out.println(par.getSuperclass());
```

Assume the parameter of the method we have is a class called "PlayerDeathEvent", which extends the abstract "Event" class.

That being said, the output would be:

```
java.lang.Class
org.mypackage.Event
```

Is there a reason why this is occurring? I found a way around this with getCanonicalName, but I'm very curious as to why this occurs.

Comment: Stop calling `getClass()` and `getSuperclass()`.  `par` is already a java.lang.Class object.  Just do `System.out.println(par);`.

Comment: Saying explicitly "stop calling" these methods is a terrible comment.

Comment: I apologize.  I'd edit it if I could.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`getClass()` method is a method in `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) that returns the `Class` object for the instance.  You have a `Class` object, so `getClass()` returns the `Class` object for the `Class` class -- a different `Class` than what `par` is an instance of.

However, the [`getSuperclass()` method, defined in `Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass--), returns the `Class` object for the superclass of the class, not of the `Class` returned by `getClass()`.

To get `PlayerDeathEvent`, call [`getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--) instead.

```
System.out.println(par.getName());
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You're right; `getName()` is better.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`par` is a object of `Class` here:

```
Class<?> par = params[0];
```

[`getClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) is from `java.lang.Object`. It returns the class (type) of the object.

So if `s` is a `String`

```
String s = "test";
```

`s.getClass` returns `String"`. 
By the same logic, `par.getClass()` returns `Class`.

[`getSuperClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass()), on the other hand, is defined `java.lang.Class` which returns the superclass of the class being represented.

So if `s` is a `String`, and c is a class that holds the reflective `Class`:

```
String s = "test";
Class c = s.getClass();
```

`s.getClass` returns `String`
`c.getSuperClass` returns `Object` because `Object` is `String`s super class
`c.getName` returns `String` and
`c.getClass` returns `Class`

---

You are probably looking for 
[`getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName())